# Playerprefs Adding Ints

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I am aware of the `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("counter", 1);` but I am trying to make a counter, and save the counter score. There was no `PlayerPrefs.AddInt("Counter", 1);` and am a bit stuck.

Comment: Have you tried `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("counter") + 1`?

Comment: @Abion47 more specifically, `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("counter", (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("counter") + 1));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `AddInt`. You have to read the old `int` with `PlayerPrefs.GetInt`, increment the data you read by `1` then save it back with `PlayerPrefs.SetInt`.

You should not save the value each time you increment. Increment during game-play but **only** save when you are about to exit the game or go to the next scene. This will make sure that constantly reading and writing data during game-play does not affect performance.

If you still insist on doing this then here is a Helper class that can do that:

```
namespace EXT
{
    public class PlayerPrefs
    {
        public static void AddInt(string key, int numberToAdd)
        {
            //Check if the key exist
            if (UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.HasKey(key))
            {
                //Read old value
                int value = UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key);

                //Increment
                value += numberToAdd;

                //Save it back
                UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetInt(key, value);
            }
        }

        public static void SubstractInt(string key, int numberToSubstract)
        {
            //Check if the key exist
            if (UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.HasKey(key))
            {
                //Read old value
                int value = UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key);

                //De-Increment
                value -= numberToSubstract;

                //Save it back
                UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetInt(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
//Add one
EXT.PlayerPrefs.AddInt("Counter", 1);
//Substract one
EXT.PlayerPrefs.SubstractInt("Counter", 1);
```